# Cannot tokenize string in JavaScript keeping all punctuation symbols

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to **tokenize** a string based on a Regular Expression: `/[\w'-]+|[^\w\s]+/g` in JavaScript into its corresponding words with proper punctuation symbols.

**My RegEx is failing in these use cases:**

```js
let text = `Hello-world.`;
let text2 = `I'm Kunal`;
let text3 = `... that Manhattan vegetarian restaurant Dirt Candy is "waging war on the 'eat your vegetables' mind-set"?`;


console.log(JSON.stringify(text.match(/[\w'-]+|[^\w\s]+/g), undefined, 4));
console.log(JSON.stringify(text2.match(/[\w'-]+|[^\w\s]+/g), undefined, 4));
console.log(JSON.stringify(text3.match(/[\w'-]+|[^\w\s]+/g), undefined, 4));
```

---

My Regex is failing in these cases:

[image]

---

To sum it up, I am not able to tokenize on some characters like: `-`, `'`, `?`, `.` and others like it and my Regex is breaking in the above use-cases.

## Edit:

The Punctuation Symbols are shared as the English Language, most of them are:

- `.` -> Period
- `,` -> Comma
- `!` -> Exclamation Mark
- `?`  -> Question Mark
- `:` -> Colon
- `;` -> Semi-Colon
- `~` -> Tilde
- `-` -> Hyphen
- `-` -> Dash
- `&` -> Ampersand
- `...` -> Ellipsis
- `""` -> Double Quotes
- `''` -> Single Quotes
- `[ and ]` -> Brackets
- `{ , }` -> Braces
- `( and )` -> Paranthesis
- `|` -> Horizontal Line
- `\ and /` -> Forward and backward slashes
- `*` -> Asterisk
- `^` -> Caret
- `$` -> Dollar sign
- `#` -> Hash/Pound sign
- `@` -> At symbol

So the split rules are: split the string at word end and at the above mentioned punctuations.

---

I also want to filter the escape sequences as a single token.

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bwdxcvxz/) to my solution.

Comment: Do you mean you need to match the special chars as single tokens?
 `/[\w'-]+|[^\w\s]/g`?

Comment: No, its just not splitting at the punctuations, take for instance: `hello-world.` the tokenized output must be: [`hello`, `-`, `world`, `.` ] splitting all punctuations and not replacing them. Take a look at the above table.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, I want to match them as single tokens.

Comment: Then you just need [`/\w+|[^\w\s]/g`](https://jsfiddle.net/bwdxcvxz/3/).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you please explain the approach you took with your Regex in an answer?

Comment: One more thing: is `_` a word char, or is it special for you? What is the expected output for `abc_def`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry I didnt get that, come again?

Comment: What is the expected output for `abc_def`?

Comment: `abc_def` should be a single word and shouldn't be tokenized. [`abc_def`]

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Are there any cases where this Regex could fail?

Comment: Sorry, it all depends on what you need and what input you run against it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew For this input: `Hello \n World` its failing, its splitting `"\"` and  `nWorld`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/\\[^]|\.{3}|\w+|[^\w\s]/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lCpv3l/4).

**Details**

- `\\[^]` - match a `\` followed with any char
- `|` - or
- `\.{3}` - match 3  dots
- `|` - or
- `\w+` - matches one or more word chars (letters, digits or `_`)
- `|` - or
- `[^\w\s]` - matches any char other than a word and whitespace char.

JS demo:

```js
let text = `Hello-world.`;
let text2 = `I'm Kunal`;
let text3 = `... that Manhattan vegetarian restaurant Dirt Candy is "waging war on the 'eat your vegetables' mind-set"?`;
let text4=`abc_def`;
let text5=`Hello\\nWorld`;

console.log(text.match(/\\[^]|\.{3}|\w+|[^\w\s]/g));
console.log(text2.match(/\\[^]|\.{3}|\w+|[^\w\s]/g));
console.log(text3.match(/\\[^]|\.{3}|\w+|[^\w\s]/g));
console.log(text4.match(/\\[^]|\.{3}|\w+|[^\w\s]/g));
console.log(text5.match(/\\[^]|\.{3}|\w+|[^\w\s]/g));
```

Comment: For this input: Hello \n World its failing, its splitting `"\"` and `nWorld`

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Yes, it is correct. It should be like this acc. to your logic: you split word chars from non-word chars. If you have a newline, it will be split upon (i.e. it will be missing in the results).

Comment: But I also want to filter the escape sequences as a single token.

Comment: Yes, this is the match I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: :) I have just realized that you edited the question to require `Hello \nWorld` to be split as two tokens, but if you use [`/\\[^]|\.{3}|\w+|[^\w\s]/g`](https://regex101.com/r/lCpv3l/4) the `\n` will be part of the resulting array. Please be specific. I will edit the answer once I understand what you really need.

Comment: Like for instance: `Hello\tWorld` should tokenize into this: `["Hello", "\t", "world"]`, which is what is happening with your [regex](https://regex101.com/r/lCpv3l/4).

Comment: Ok, then please edit the question like this: *Also for the input `Hello \nWorld`, the tokenized array must be: `['Hello', '\t', 'World']`*